# Two-Dimensional array (IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to make an algorithm, which counts how many numbers are divided without a remainder.

```
d=[]
for i in range (0, 10001):
    for c in range (1, 16):
        if i % c == 0: d[c] += 1
```

I expect to have something like this

```
/1:  10000
/2:  5000
/3:  3334
/4:  2500
/5:  2000
/6:  1667
/7:  1429
/8:  1250
/9:  1112
/10:  1000
/11:  910
/12:  834
/13:  770
/14:  715
/15:  667
```

, but i get `IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fill the list with zeros:

```
d = [0] * 17  # <== THIS
for i in range (0, 10001):
    for c in range (1, 16):
        if i % c == 0: d[c] += 1
```

Note that this has an extraneous zero at the start (i.e. `d[0]`).  Very easy to ignore.

Also, your counts are off by one compared to what your code actually does (for example, there are `10001` even numbers in your range and not `10000`).

Answer (score 2):

You can't add to an element of a list that has never been created.